# Convert lists in hashmap to a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, hashmap

So I've a hashmap defined as : `hashmap<String,LinkedList<node>>`.
The node class contains two fields a and b.

I've a number of string values for which I need information.
What I want to do is go through the hashmap and look for the Linkedlists associated with each value that I've and get the list for the fields 'a' into a 2d array.

So all 'a' fields of string value "animal" to be the first array in the 2d array. All 'a' fields of string value "humans" to be in the second array and so on and so forth.

I know its kind off a mess but I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a List of List instead of a 2D Array, Because I'm sure the Rows and columns will very and you may not know the initial size ahead of time for each.

I made a few assumptions since you did not specify. You can made modifications as needed to work for your specific scenario. see assumptions below.

> Assumptions

1. The "Strings" you care about i.e. "Animal", "Human" are the Keys of your `hashMap`.
2. the field `a` in `Node` class is of Type `String`
3. You have a list for all the Strings you care about

> Implementation

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    Map<String, LinkedList<Node>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<Node>>();
    List<List<String>> multiDemList = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); //Once the method is done this will contain your 2D list
    List<String> needInfoOn = new ArrayList<String>(); //This should contain all of the HashMap Keys you are interested in i.e. Animal, Human keys

    for(String s: needInfoOn){
        if(!hashMap.containsKey(s)) continue; //if the map doesnt contain this string then skip to the next so we dont add empty rows in our multidimensional array. remove this line if you want empty rows
        List<String> list = BuildTypeAList(hashMap, s);
        multiDemList.add(list);
    }
}

private static List<String> BuildTypeAList(Map<String, LinkedList<Node>> map, String s) {
    LinkedList<Node> linkedList = map.get(s);
    ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Node n: linkedList) {
        arrList.add(n.a);
    }
    return arrList;
}

private static class Node {
    String a;
    String b;
}
```